# Can I replay missions?

Tags: ghost-recon-future-soldier

When I push △ to go to the intel map and pick the mission I want to replay, it just plays a video and goes back. Can I replay missions? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. To do so, you have to push Start and quit back to the main menu. Then load your game again and pick Mission Selection instead of Continue Mission. The intel map's apparently just for catching up on the story.